# Using TagLib (C++ Library) in Objective-C Mac App

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, taglib

I'm looking to use [TagLib](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib.html), a C++ library for getting tagging information from a variety of audio files, in a new Objective-C project.

1. Does anyone have experience using a C++ library such as this in an Objective-C project?
2. What kind of roadblocks should I expect?
3. Can anyone point me a good tutorials or guides for this subject?

Also... is TagLib even a good choice? I need to support MP3, WMA, FLAC, MP4, M4A, AAC, and OGG files. I don't believe there is a native Mac framework that will support all of these.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very easy to mix Objective-C and C++; there is practically no problem. [Read this documentation at Apple.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html) As described there, there is something called Objective-C++, which allows you to mix C++ and Objective-C++ in the same file. In XCode, just use a file extension `.mm`  to use Objective-C++.

It does not attempt to unify at all the Objective-C objects and C++ objects; you can just use them simultaneously, independently. So the Objective-C objects are managed by `retain`/`release`, and C++ objects are managed by `new`/`delete`. There are a few tricky things like putting a non-pointer C++ object as an ivar inside an Objective-C class, but if you always use C++ pointers (instead of non-pointer objects) you won't face any major problem.

Comment: I did just discover this as well. May be a great starting point: https://github.com/rahvin/TagLib.framework

Comment: Update... Gave up on using TagLib within Objective-C. The library compiled fine, but refused to work within an application. Moving to Java instead and using jAudioTagger. http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/